# Add a clientEvent filter to an AJAX fullCalendar

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar, filtering

I'm trying to add a clientEvent filter to an already working AJAX fullCalendar. The idea is to allow the visitor to filter the events already displayed by selecting a choice in a droping list.

The code is currently as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.post(             
                MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                {
                    action: 'get_fullcalendar',
                    data: {
                        slotbegin: start.unix(), // données à compléter
                        slotend: end.unix()         
                    }
                },
                function( events ) {
                    callback( events );
                }

            );
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.qtip({
                id: 'eventdetails',
                content: {
                    text: event.image + event.description,
                    title: event.title
                },
            });
        }

    });


    $("#cible_select").change(function() {
        var cible = $(this).val()
        var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt) {
            return evt.public_cible == cible;
        });
    });

});
```

The fullCalendar works OK by itself. But I don't know how to integrate the clientEvents bit so it is used when the user makes change to the #cible_select selector.
I've been trying many things for the past hours, and would appreciate some help to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

This function might help you. call this function where ever you want.

```js
function parseClientEvents(/*pass params here*/){
        var clientArr = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        for(i in clientArr){
            console.log(clientArr[i]);
            //all your logic goes here.  
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have misunderstood the way `clientEvents` works. I thought it would re-display the whole calendar with the selected events only, but that's not the case.
`removeEvents` works to hide/suppress events one doesn't want any more, but those are not available on the client side any more, so `refetchEvents` has to be used if the user changes his mind and makes another choice.
`removeEventSource` works only if you have a limited number of sources, and I want to be able to combine several filters, so there is quite a number of combinations.

So, I'm completely rethinking my filtering strategy: `clientEvents` is definitely not the way to toggle on/off events on a multicriteria basis.